# Excel QUOTIENT in array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to use QUOTIENT function in array formula, but it return error

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
={SUM(($D3:$D10000=$I3)*(IF(QUOTIENT($F3:$F10000;J$2)>0;30;$F3:$F10000)))}
```

Need to fill table with sums
How to write right syntax?

Comment: have you stepped through the calculations to see what's causing the issue?  It may be helpful to shorten your range and post a sample of your data so people can test.

Comment: I think quotient cannot be used in matricial way. Maybe you should try something like  `=INT($F3:$F10000/J$2)` because I had problems in the past and something like this worked for me

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Just thought I'd point out that unlike TRUNC, INT will not return the same results as QUOTIENT when dealing with negative numbers.

Comment: @Domenic Nice point there,. You are right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like QUOTIENT cannot return an array of values.  Instead, try...

```
=SUM(IF($D3:$D10000=$I3;IF(TRUNC($F3:$F10000/J$2)>0;30;$F3:$F10000)))
```